# Refactor code to make 3 size array dynamic in code

Tags: c#

I want to refactor the code, I need to make this code dynamic, how to do that, see below part?

```
public class Trv34
{
    public string CustomerNumber
    public string ProductName
}

Models.Trv34[] itemTrv34 = new Models.Trv34[3] 
itemTrv34[0] = new Models.Trv34 {CustomerNumber ="1", ProductName="p1"}
itemTrv34[1] = new Models.Trv34 {CustomerNumber ="2", ProductName="p2"}
itemTrv34[2] = new Models.Trv34 {CustomerNumber ="3", ProductName="p3"}

request.VODB.Trv34= new Models.Trv34[] {
       itemTrv34[0],
       itemTrv34[1],
       itemTrv34[2],
};
```

I want to replace this part with something dynamic instead

```
        itemTrv34[0],
        itemTrv34[1],
        itemTrv34[2],
```

Comment: By "dynamic", do you mean "able to have more than 3 elements at any point in time"?

Comment: Yes more/less than 3 elements

Comment: Use a `List<T>`, however i'm down-voting for lack of information, and voting to close as unclear until you can better explain what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way that comes to mind is to use Linq:

```
request.VODB.Trv34 = itemTrv34.ToArray();
```

Comment: This was the solution for me, Im bad to explain what I want